# Find general formula for the terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find a general formula for the terms of the sequence
>
> $${a_n}=\left\{ \frac{11}{7},\frac{107}{49},\frac{659}{343},\frac{4883}{2401},\frac{33371}{16807},\frac{234569}{117649},\dots \right\}$$

I don't know how to approach this question as it is not arithmetic or geometric. I know the denominator is geometric increasing by a factor of $7$ but I can't find what the numerator should be for the general formula for the terms. Anyone know what it is?

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: My online calculus questions platform called Mobius(used to be Maple TA). I believe it must be a mistake as nothing I input is giving me the correct answer.

Comment: Have you put it into OEIS?

Comment: This is in the OEIS, but not much else - https://oeis.org/A081657

Comment: Nobody can tell you the correct answer. Whatever answer you give, the proposer can tell you that you are wrong. You an't win this kind of game.

Answer (score 7):

The general formula for an (infinite) sequence of (e. g. real) numbers from the finite number $n$ of its (first) members is **in principle impossible,** as the next (not listed) $(n+1)^\mathrm{th}$ member may be an *arbitrary* number, and *there is still a formula for expressing* $a_1, \dots, a_n, a_{n+1},$ e. g. as a polynomial of order $n$:

$$a_k = \sum_{i=0}^nb_ik^i,\quad k = 1, \dots,n+1$$

The process for finding coefficients $b_0, \dots, b_n$ is [straightforward enough](http://2000clicks.com/MathHelp/GeometryPointsDeterminePolynomial.aspx).

In other words, if someone will find the formula for your "sequence", there is still the *infinity number of other formulas*, giving different sequences, but *all of them producing your "sequence",* i. e. $$\frac{11}{7},\frac{107}{49},\frac{659}{343},\frac{4883}{2401},\frac{33371}{16807},\frac{234569}{117649}.$$

---

*Note:*

It means that all psychological tests of type

> What is the next number of the sequence $1, 2, 3, 4, 5?$

are *in principle meaningless ones*, because you may tell "$1762$", and then show to surprised psychologist a formula supporting the correctness of your answer:

$$a_k = {439\over30}k^5-{439\over 2}k^4+{7463\over 6}k^3-{6585\over 2}k^2+{60158\over 15}k-1756$$

If he/she will not trust you, launch [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), which will produce accurate, non-rounded results, and write commands

```
sage: var("k")
sage: a(k) = (439/30)*k^5 - (439/2)*k^4+(7463/6)*k^3-(6585/2)*k^2+(60158/15)*k-1756
sage: a(1), a(2), a(3), a(4), a(5), a(6), a(7), a(8)
```

to obtain the result

> ```
> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1762, 10543, 36884)
> ```

(and to give the psychologist two more members for free).

---

*Note 2:*

It doesn't mean that there is not a simpler formula - including a recurrent one or other "recipe" - for the same (finite) sequence.

For example, there is *so simple one* for the rather not so trivial sequence

$$\color{blue}{1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221}$$

that even *6-7 year-old child is able to write down the next element* ($\color{red}{312211}$) if you tell it the rule, or - perhaps - even without telling it.

No, you have no chance to discover this simple rule (supposing your age is $10$+). Don't waste your time. It's a good advice, believe me.

(Googling for it is a *much better* approach.)

Answer (score 5):

The general term seems to be
$$a_n=\frac{2(7^n)+(-3)^n}{7^n}=2+\left(-\frac{3}{7}\right)^n$$
But the last term is given by
$$a_6=2-\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^6$$
so this formula does not always work. A suitable formula could be
$$a_n=\begin{cases}2-\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n&n\equiv0\mod{6}\\
2+\left(-\frac{3}{7}\right)^n &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

The numerator of the $n$-th term seems to be
$$2\cdot 7^n+(-1)^n 3^n. $$

Comment: May I ask how you got to this answer? Or is trial and error the only method?Edit: I inputted this answer into the online question and it came out as incorrect.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but what about the last term? $234569\ne 2(7^6)+3^6$

Comment: @PeterForeman Arg, yes, the last is $2(7)^6\color{red}{-}3^6$!

Comment: @RaV1oLLi: I noticed the numerators are the successive powers of $7$, and the numerators were not far from twice the denominator, with a corrective term.  So I subtracted twice the denominators from the numerators, and tried to see a pattern. I tested only the 5 first terms.