# Write an explicit rule

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What’s the explicit rule for for this number sequence?

$$\displaystyle{1 \over 100},\ -{3 \over 95},\ {5 \over 90},\
-{7 \over 85},\ {9 \over 80}$$

The numerator changes to negative every other term, while the denominator subtracts $5$ every term.

Comment: Do a separate sequence for both and then put it together. You will also need to take the alternating sign in concern too.

Answer (score 3):

with convention we start from $n= 0$, $x_n = \frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)}{100-5n}$  for $n=0,1, \ldots, 19$

Comment: What happens when $n=20?$

Comment: well the sequence isn't defined there, so neither is it's general term

Answer (score 0):

The general formula for an (infinite) sequence of (e. g. real) numbers from the finite number $n$ of its (first) members is **in principle impossible,** as the next (not listed) $(n+1)^\mathrm{th}$ member may be an *arbitrary* number, and *there is still a formula for expressing* $a_1, \dots, a_n, a_{n+1}$.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3196103/393259), in which is for the question

> What is the next number of the sequence $1, 2, 3, 4, 5?$

proved by the appropriate formula, that the **next number is $\color{red}{1762}.$**